# Does disabling SSLv2 and SSLv3 have any breaking changes on the end user?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

We have clients who can be using anything, WindowsXP,Vista,Linux....
Currently our systems support SSLV2 and SSLV3.But, we are planning to disable both SSLV2 and SSLV3 in windows server 2008R2 in favour of TLS 1.2. 
Will it have any breaking changes with the end user?I'm worried that If I disable SSLV3  ( and SSLV2) , some of the clients who use windowsXP(for example) might not be able to access my web service.

PS: Tried to find a similar question in stackoverflow, didn't find any. So, posting this as a question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the scenarios where you will NOT be able to support old clients using insecure protocols and expect to have decent security.

1. If you have not enabled TLS 1.2 yet, do so.
2. Some clients do not support TLS 1.2 (e.g., older Android versions). You may need to support TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in addition to 1.2. While not ideal, it is definitely better than supporting SSL 2.0 and 3.0.
3. Post an announcement indicating that your web service is being upgraded to meet minimum security requirements and set a date for retiring insecure protocols.
4. Optionally, check your server metrics to see what protocols/ ciphers are used. Since you haven't mentioned your web server, I'm assuming it is IIS, in which case this is not easy[[1]](https://serverfault.com/questions/724308/how-can-one-measure-the-breakdown-of-visitors-that-support-tls-1-2)[[2]](https://serverfault.com/questions/531830/logging-ssl-ciphersuite-used-in-windows-server-2008-r2).
5. Retire SSL 2.0 and SSL 3.0. There will be a few clients who will not be able to connect. Plan to have an answer ready for them. If you have clients running XP and using IE6, they have bigger issues than not being able to access your web service.
6. While you are at it, run your TLS configuration through an online
   scanner like [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) to ensure you fix any other issues.